# Is $\operatorname{height} \mathfrak{p} + \dim A / \mathfrak{p} = \dim A$ true?

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra

> Let $A$ be an integral domain of finite Krull dimension. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal. Is it true that $$\operatorname{height} \mathfrak{p} + \dim A / \mathfrak{p} = \dim A$$
>   where $\dim$ refers to the Krull dimension of a ring?

Hartshorne states it as Theorem 1.8A in Chapter I (for the case $A$ a finitely-generated $k$-algebra which is an integral domain) and cites Matsumura and Atiyah–Macdonald, but I haven't been able to find anything which looks relevant in either. (Disclaimer: I know nothing about dimension theory, and very little commutative algebra.) If it is true (under additional assumptions, if need be), where can I find a complete proof?

It is obvious that $$\operatorname{height} \mathfrak{p} + \dim A/\mathfrak{p} \le \dim A$$ by a lifting argument, but the reverse inequality is eluding me.  Localisation doesn't seem to be the answer, since localisation can change the dimension...

Comment: This is not true in general. The keyword is the catenary ring: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary_ring.

Comment: As George's answer shows, "catenary" is not enough.

Comment: This is explained in Matsumura's Commutative algebra book though. See (14.H) COROLLARY 3.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yours is a very interesting and subtle question, which  often generates  confusion. First let us give a name to the property you are interested in: a ring  $A$ will be said to satisfy  **(DIM)** if for all $\mathfrak p \in \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ we have $$\operatorname{height}(\mathfrak p) +\dim A/\mathfrak p=\dim(A) \quad \quad (\text{DIM})$$
The main misconception is to believe that this follows from catenarity:
**Fact 1: A catenary ring, or even a universally catenary ring, does not satisfy (DIM) in general.**
**Counterexample:** Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a discrete valuation ring whose maximal ideal has uniformizing parameter $\pi$, i.e.  $\mathfrak m =(\pi)$. Let $A=R[T]$,  the polynomial ring over $R$. The ring $A$ has dimension $2.$ Then for the maximal ideal $\mathfrak p=(\pi T-1)$, the relation  (DIM) is false: 
$\operatorname{height}(\mathfrak p)+\dim A/\mathfrak p= 1+0=1\neq 2=\dim (A)$.
And this even though $A$ is as nice as can be: an integral domain, noetherian, regular, *universally catenary*,...

Happily here are two  positive results:

**Fact 2: A finitely generated integral algebra over a field satisfies (DIM)** (and is universally catenary).
So, by the algebro-geometric dictionary, an affine variety $X$ has the pleasant property that for each  integral subvariety $Y\subset X$ we have, as hoped, $\operatorname{dimension}(Y) + \operatorname{codimension}(Y)$ $=$ $\operatorname{dimension}(X).$

**Fact 3: A Cohen-Macaulay local ring satisfies (DIM)** (and is universally catenary).
For example a regular ring is Cohen-Macaulay. This "explains" why my counter-example above was not local.

**The paradox resolved.**  How is it possible for a catenary ring $A$ not to satisfy (DIM)? Here is how. If you have an inclusion of two primes $\mathfrak p\subsetneq \mathfrak q$ catenarity says that you can complete it to a saturated chain of primes 
$\mathfrak p\subsetneq  \mathfrak p_1\subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq \mathfrak p_{r-1} \subsetneq \mathfrak q$ and that all such completions will have length the same length $r$. Fine. But what can you say if you have just one prime $\mathfrak p$ ? Not much! The catenary ring $A$ may have dimension $\dim(A) > \operatorname{height}( \mathfrak p) +\dim(A/\mathfrak p)$ because it possesses a long chain of primes *avoiding* the prime  $\mathfrak p$ altogether. In my counterexample above the only saturated chain of primes containing $\mathfrak p=(\pi T-1)$ is $0\subsetneq \mathfrak p$. However the ring $A$ has dimension 2 because of the saturated chain of primes $0\subsetneq (\pi)  \subsetneq (\pi,T)$, which *avoids* $\mathfrak p$.

**Addendum.** Here is why the ideal $\mathfrak p$ in the counter-example is maximal. We have $A/\mathfrak p=R[T]/(\pi T-1)=R[1/\pi]=\operatorname{Frac}(R)$, since the fraction field of a discrete valuation ring can be obtained just by inverting a uniformizing parameter. So $A/\mathfrak p$ is a field and $\mathfrak p$ is maximal.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the catenary thing. I think the correct statement is that a "catenary, equidimensional (equicodimensional?) ring satisfies DIM.

Comment: Dear Akhil,I don't know about equidimensional rings, although I more or less guess what it means . I have a suspicion that this would be a little tautological, but I'd love to be shown wrong: what family of rings not finitely generated over a field would have this property?

Comment: Thanks for the this answer! Seems like I had a big misunderstanding of this issue..

Comment: Dear Soarer, don't worry: that catenary implies (DIM) is one of the most widespread misconceptions I have ever met (and I spent quite some time trying to clear these issues for myself).

Comment: @Georges: Dear Georges, am I missing something here? Consider the variety which is a disjoint union of a line and a plane. This has dimension two. If we pick the subvariety consisting of a point in the line, then the dimension is zero and the codimension is one, no? I certainly agree that the equality holds for irreducible varieties though.

Comment: Equidimensional is defined in EGA 0-IV.14 as all irreducible components having the same dimension; equicodimensional is that all minimal irreducible closed sets have the same codimension. A noetherian space of finite dimension is biequidimensional if and only if the equality (DIM) is verified, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Dear Akhil, you cannot take a point plus a line because a variety is reduced and irreducible in my context, since it corresponds in the algebro-geometric dictionary to the finitely generated integral algebra of Fact 2. As for EGA 0-IV.14, I've just had a look. It seems to be a compendium of definitions and  soft results with two-line proofs. The authors remark themselves that some results are even valid in any ordered set. So, again, I don't see how these ideas could yield rings satisfying (DIM). Anyway, thanks for the reference and your interest. (By the way, have you read all of EGA?)

Comment: Ah, ok. Then I agree with your claim. Also, I agree that 0-IV.14 is mostly content-free. The real content, that (DIM) holds for integral domains finitely generated over a field, is in IV-5.2.1 (though catenary-ness is deduced from the fact that a regular local ring is universally catenary; the way I always thought of the result was via the transcendence degree additivity. (I certainly haven't read all of EGA.)

Comment: I think it is also worth noticing that when a ring satisfies (DIM) for prime ideals, then the dimensional equality holds for any ideal: If $I$ is an arbitrary ideal and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal over $I$ with $ht(I) = ht(p)$, then the quotient map $R/I \to R/\mathfrak{p}$ is surjective, so the induced spectra map is injective, yielding $\dim R/I \ge \dim R/\mathfrak{p}$. So we have $\dim R/\mathfrak{p} \le \dim R/I \le \dim R - ht(I) = \dim R- ht(\mathfrak{p})$, and since DIM holds for prime ideals, the equality follows.

Comment: Incidentally, this nice counterexample is already stated in EGA IV, Remarque 5.2.5(i).

Comment: Any reference for Fact 3?

Comment: @Cyclicduck [The Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00N7) Lemma 10.104.4

Comment: Perhaps the reason for the "widespread misconception" is that for a Noetherian local domain, (DIM) is equivalent to being catenary (as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1545880))

Answer (score 7):

Although this is an old question, I thought it was worth mentioning a recent paper by [Heinrich](https://doi.org/10.1216/JCA-2017-9-1-49) that corrects the statements in [EGA$0_{\text{IV}}$](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1964__20__5_0) mentioned in the comments.

Let us start with some definitions (following [[Heinrich](https://doi.org/10.1216/JCA-2017-9-1-49), Def. 1.2, Prop. 4.1]):

**Definition.**  Let $X$ be a topological space which is $T_0$, noetherian, and finite dimensional.

1. The space $X$ is *biequidimensional* if all maximal chains of irreducible closed subsets of $X$ have the same length.
2. The space $X$ is *weakly biequidimensional* if it is equidimensional, equicodimensional, and catenary.

The often cited result from [EGA$0_{\text{IV}}$](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1964__20__5_0) is the following:

**Claim** [[EGA$0_{\text{IV}}$](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1964__20__5_0), Prop. 14.3.3]**.** *Let $X$ be a topological space which is $T_0$, noetherian, and finite dimensional. The following are equivalent:*

1. *The space $X$ is biequidimensional.*
2. *The space $X$ is weakly biequidimensional.*
3. *The space $X$ is equicodimensional and for every inclusion of irreducible closed subsets $Y \subseteq Z$ in $X$, we have*
   $$\dim(Z) = \dim(Y) + \operatorname{codim}(Y,Z).$$
4. *The space $X$ is equicodimensional and for every inclusion of irreducible closed subsets $Y \subseteq Z$ in $X$, we have*
   $$\operatorname{codim}(Y,X) = \operatorname{codim}(Y,Z) + \operatorname{codim}(Z,X).$$

This is not quite correct, as was found independently by Gabber and by Chen (see [[ILO](http://fabrice.orgogozo.perso.math.cnrs.fr/travaux_de_Gabber/), Exp. XV, §2.4, footnote (i) on p. 196]), and also by Heinrich [[Heinrich](https://doi.org/10.1216/JCA-2017-9-1-49)].

Gabber and Heinrich both noted that (1), (3), and (4) are equivalent (see [[Heinrich](https://doi.org/10.1216/JCA-2017-9-1-49), Lem. 2.3] for a proof), and Heinrich showed that these conditions imply (2) [[Heinrich](https://doi.org/10.1216/JCA-2017-9-1-49), Lem. 2.1]. Gabber and Heinrich both gave examples where (2) does not imply (3); we reproduce Heinrich's here:

**Example** [[Heinrich](https://doi.org/10.1216/JCA-2017-9-1-49), Ex. 3.7]**.** The ring $A$ obtained by localizing the ring
$$\frac{k[v, w, x, y]}{(vy, wy)}$$
away from the union $(v,w,x,y-1) \cup (v,w,y)$ is weakly biequidimensional but does not satisfy (3): setting $Y = V(v,w,x,y-1) \subsetneq V(v,w) = Z$, we have
$$\dim(Z) = 2 > 0 + 1 = \dim(Y) + \operatorname{codim}(Y,Z).$$
See [[Heinrich](https://doi.org/10.1216/JCA-2017-9-1-49), Ex. 3.7] for details.

A preprint by [Emerton and Gee](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.07654v3) gives a correct variant of the Claim above; see [[Emerton and Gee](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.07654v3), Lem. 2.32]. The basic difference is that the Claim is true if $X$ is assumed to be irreducible. Gabber also gives a variant where (2) is replaced by "$X$ is catenary and equidimensional and its irreducible components are equicodimensional" [[ILO](http://fabrice.orgogozo.perso.math.cnrs.fr/travaux_de_Gabber/), Exp. XV, §2.4, footnote (i) on p. 196].

Answer (score 6):

The statement with the hypotheses given in Hartshorne is true.

For a reference, see COR 13.4 on pg. 290 of Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra*.

The general idea of proof is this: 
Consider a maximal chain of prime ideals in $A$ which includes the given prime $\mathfrak p$, the length of which is dim $A$ (see Thm A, pg. 290 of Eisenbud).  It follows that $\dim A = \operatorname{height} \mathfrak p + \dim A/\mathfrak p$.

Comment: You are specifying a prime $p$ here, while OP was asking about arbitrary prime.

Comment: @Soarer: I'm not sure what you mean.  Given an arbitrary prime $\mathfrak p$, construct a maximal chain of prime ideals which includes $\mathfrak p$.  Every maximal chain of primes in $A$ has the same length, i.e. the Krull dimension of $A$, although this assertion itself is not trivial, but the full proof is in Eisenbud.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a useful situation where $A$ is not necessarily an integral domain. It generalizes Fact 2 from Georges's answer and specializes (1) $\rightarrow$ (3) from Takumi's answer.

**Definition 1.** Let $A$ be a finitely generated algebra over a field $k$. $A$ is called *equidimensional* if all minimal primes of $A$ have the same height.

**Theorem 1.** Suppose $A$ is an equidimensional $k$-algebra. Then $\operatorname{height} P + \dim A/P = \dim A$ for any $P \in \operatorname{Spec} A$.

Here is the scheme-theoretic picture.

**Definition 2.** Let $X$ be a $k$-scheme. $X$ is called *equidimensional* if its irreducible components have all the same dimension.

**Theorem 2.** Let $X$ be an equidimensional $k$-scheme locally of finite type. Let $Y$ be an irreducible closed subscheme with generic point $\eta$. Then $\dim \mathcal{O}_{X,\eta} + \dim Y = \dim X$.

Comment: Theorem 1 is a mild generalization of the affine domain case.