# Krull dimension in polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and $R=F[X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n]$ be the polynomial ring in $n$ variables over $F$ and $P$ be a prime ideal in $R$, I'm trying to prove that$$\operatorname{ht}P+\dim R/P=\dim R$$where $\dim$ is the Krull dimension of a ring.
Any ideas, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathrm{ht}(P) + \dim(R/P) \leq \dim(R)$ is trivial, but the converse is not so easy to prove directly. You can find a proof in several books on algebraic geometry, for example Qing Liu's *Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves*, Proposition 2.5.23. Another reference is the [CRing Project](http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~amathew/cr.html), Theorem §10.3.22. It holds more generally for every domain which is a finitely generated $F$-algebra (this generalization is important for the induction step).

For a more detailed discussion about the equation, see [math.SE/49136](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49136).

Comment: Thank you for your help Martin. I'll look for the book and find the proof, thank you again.

Comment: This is also Theorem 15.12 in the book $\textit{A Term of Commutative Algebra}$ by Altman&Kleiman, after the observation that we always have $\mathrm{ht}(P)=\dim(R_P)$, where $R_P$ is the localization at $P$.

Comment: Is $\operatorname{ht}I+\dim R/I=\dim R$ true for all ideals instead of just prime ideals?