# Dimension property of certain rings involving localization and quotient by primes?

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, dimension-theory-algebra

Following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49285/1072684), let us make the following definition:

> Definition: We say a comm ring $R$ has the "DIM property" iff for every prime ideal $p \subset R$, we have
> $$
> \mathrm{dim}(R_p) + \mathrm{dim}(R/p) = \mathrm{dim}(R)\,.
> $$

- The answer linked above says that $R$ of the following kinds of rings have the DIM property:

  - integral domains which are also algebra-finitely-generated over a field (or $\mathbb{Z}$; see [this bachelor's thesis](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Epink/Theses/2017-Bachelor-Anna-Bot.pdf), page 1, (i) in the 2nd Theorem);
  - and, local Cohen-Macaulay rings.
- (For completeness: the author of the 1st link above also cautions that catenary, even universally catenary, rings generally need not have the DIM property.)

<s>I was wondering if anyone could suggest a source which discusses the details of the proofs of the above statements about the mentioned algebra-fin-gen domains, and local Cohen-Macaulay rings, having the DIM property?</s>

Edit: Thanks to the comments below for providing [these](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00N7) [two](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00OO) references.

However, does anyone have a reference which specifically shows the DIM property for finite-gen algebras over $\mathbb{Z}$, not just fields?

---

Note: my motivation in considering this is Exercise 11.1.I of Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry; if I'm not mistaken this DIM property must be enforced on the values of the structure sheaf of $X$ on open sets.

For reference, the exercise is to prove:

> If $X$ is a scheme, and $Y\subset X$ is an irreducible closed subset, and $\eta$ is the generic point corresponding to $Y$,
> then the codimension of $Y$ in $X$ equals the dimension of the stalk / local ring of $X$ at $\eta$.

Comment: You might find these stacks project pages helpful: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00N7 and https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00OO