# Algebraic geometry height and prime ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $Y\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$ be algebraic. Assume $Y$ is irreducible.

Put $\mathfrak{p}=I(Y)$ , the ideal of $Y$ in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$.

Is it true that $height (\mathfrak{p})+ dim k[x_1,...,x_n]/\mathfrak{p} = \dim k[x_1,...,x_n]$?

This seems to have been used in a proof in lectures. Though I am not sure how to prove it?

Clearly $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime.

Could some care to elaborate on the intuition behind it please?

Comment: This should be in the literature somewhere, definitely in EGA. Consult [Thm 5.6.8 of these notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~r-ash/ComAlg/ComAlg5.pdf). Note that polynomial rings are affine $k$-algebras and "coht" is essentially synonym to the dimension of the quotient ring. Intuition: dimension measures "#independent parameters". By Krull's height theorem the height also measures #independent parameters" needed to define the subspace for the prime ideal. If you subtract these two numbers you should be left with #independent parameters" of the subspace, i.e. the dimension. Rough idea..

Comment: This is theorem 11.2.9 in Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, available at http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf , but the proof is given as a series of exercises.

Comment: @ThomasPreu no, that's not correct. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49136/is-operatornameheight-mathfrakp-dim-a-mathfrakp-dim-a-true/49285#49285) for more details.

Comment: My bad. Will remove the comment.

Comment: @KReiser What exactly is incorrect? Is the proof given in the linked notes incorrect? Or is it the independent parameters part that is incorrect?

Comment: @DavidLui There was another (now deleted) comment claiming the result in the question is a consequence of a ring being (universally) catenary. Unfortunately that's not correct, as the linked answer shows. I did not mean to say anything about the first comment.