# If a longest chain of prime ideals can be chosen to go through any given prime, does the same hold for inclusions of primes?

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $R$ be a commutative ring (not necessarily Noetherian) of finite Krull dimension. Suppose that for any prime ideal $p$, $\dim(R) = \dim(R/p) + \mathrm{height}(p)$ (call this condition $DIM$) .

Does that mean that for any inclusion of prime ideals $p \subsetneq q$, there is a longest chain (a chain of length $\dim(R)$) that includes both $p$ and $q$ ?

My attempt is that this would be to try to prove that a quotient and a localization at a prime ideal of a ring that satisfies $DIM$ also satisfies $DIM$. But now I think this is false. The counterexample in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49285/445002 might also be a counterexample here. I can't figure out how to write $R[t]$ (where $R$ is a DVR) as a localization at prime ideals and quotient of a ring that does satisfy $DIM$. I know that $k[x]_{(x)}$ is a DVR, and  $k[x]_{(x)}[t]$ is a localization of $k[x,t]$, but I don't think this is a localization at a prime ideal.

Comment: Every finite poset arises as $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ for some commutative ring $R$, and you can easily build a poset that satisfies DIM but not your condition

Comment: So, do you want an example of a ring satisfying DIM, but having a localization which doesn't have the property DIM?

Comment: @user26857 The localization would have to be at a prime ideal.